# How to catch the error when I upload the object using Alamofire - Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

When I test my project in the condition of no internet connection, for calling upload function, I can't catch failure situation. 
I have printed the status code but I am getting nil and shows my default value.
What's wrong with me?
And I also got this error like following text:

> ==)[r]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "似乎已断开与互联网的连接。" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1d4441560 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://appdominname/chatroom/5a3cba41f7255b356eeee33/media, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://appdominname/chatroom/5a3cba41f7255b356eeee33/media, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSLocalizedDescription=似乎已断开与互联网的连接。}
>
> ==)[c]: 123

```
func uploadPost(parameters:[String:Any], fileUrl:URL, _ callback: @escaping (JSON) -> Void)  {

    let url = self.customUrl(parameters)

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        multipartFormData.append(fileUrl, withName: "media")

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }

    }, usingThreshold: .init(), to: url, method: .post, headers:  ["Authorization": "Bearer \(currentUser.token)"]) { (encodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

                print("==)[r]:",response)
                print("==)[c]:",response.response?.statusCode ?? "123")

                if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch statusCode {
                    case 201:
                        print("success statusCode: \(statusCode)")
                    default:
                        print("error with response status: \(statusCode)")
                    }
                }

                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let json = result as! NSDictionary
                    //                        print(json["status"] ?? "")
                    callback(JSON(json))
                }
            })

        case .failure(let encodingError):

            alertWithConfirm(title: localString(string: "WARNING"), message: localString(string: "ERROR_UPLOAD_API_FAIL"), afterConfirm: { _ in
                callback(JSON(encodingError))
            })
            print("error:\(encodingError)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only contains `failure` block for encoding but not for the request itself. In your first `success` block, you should do something like

```
case .success(let upload, _, _):
    switch response.result {
        case .success:
            //THE REQUEST WAS SUCCESSFUL
        case .failure:
            //THIS IS WHERE YOU WILL GET YOUR REQUEST FAILURE
    }
```